# How to programmatically find "Largest Contentful Paint" from an HTML string

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, core-web-vitals

How can I programmatically find "Largest Contentful Paint" from an HTML string?

I have a page that its content is generated by the user, and I'd like to know on the fly (or maybe in the first page load and then cache) what is the LCP for that page, so I can do something about it (pre-load an image or add a div block).

Is there a way to do something like this (ideally via Node or PHP):

```js
const lcpElement = findLcp(htmlString);
// lcpElement will contain the LCP HTML element
```

Thank you

Comment: If you mean the one Google uses to rank websites, I doubt they'll share their exact criteria - exactly to prevent such manipulations.

Comment: But technically, the largest contenful paint is, well, the largest contenful paint, meaning the largest element in the page, so I don't think it's a secret, it's just a matter of rendering the HTML, looking at it and finding the largest element, right?

Comment: Well, *contentful* is the keyword here. I doubt an element with an image would fall in this criteria. In addition, the size of the elements is influenced by CSS, not only HTML, so you would need to actually render the content or make another complicated processing. You can try looking for a server-side DOM library but again I doubt it would help anyway.

Comment: Yes indeed. In my case, I have all styles inline, so just the HTML string would be enough. I will try to create an algorithm myself using the headless chrome, let's see.

Answer (score 2):

If using headless Chrome (as you suggested in the comments) then you can just use the PerformanceObserver to ask the browser for the LCP element.

See here:
https://web.dev/lcp/#measure-lcp-in-javascript